# How to preset which datatype must be fetched from excel to sql

Tags: excel, t-sql, oledb

I use 64-bit driver. In order to obtain data from excel I use the following select:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Data Source=C:\path\to\file.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[db1$]
```

However when there are too much first (say 5000) rows containg NULLs it sets wrong datatype and convert (corrupt) the data to the DB.

Is it possible to preset or preverify more than 5000 rows?

Note that, 5000 isn't accurate number.

Weird, following code returns corrupted data as well:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Data Source=C:\path\to\file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"')...[db1$]
```

That said IMEX=1 doesn't work...

**Update**: TypeGuessRows=0 in reg fixes it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the IMEX=1 setting mentioned here help?

http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

If not that, does this help?

http://jingyangli.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/imex1-revisit-and-typeguessrows-setting-change-to-0-watch-for-performance/

32 bit:

`Hkey_Local_Machine/Software/Microsoft/Jet/4.0/Engines/Excel/TypeGuessRows`
`Hkey_Local_Machine/Software/Microsoft/Jet/4.0/Engines/Excel/ImportMixedTypes`

64 bit:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\ImportMixedTypes`

Change:
TypeGuessRows: 0    —-Check all column values before choosing the appropriate data type.ImportMixedTypes: Text         —-import mixed-type columns as text.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the way to go. Howerver I have 64 bit related issue: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/import-excel-file-sql-server-64-bit-157244.aspx

Comment: So far can't find a way to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to fix it by appending "" to Extended Properties, it requires quotation marks for few parameters. Nevertheless, IMEX=1 didn't change the result, alas.

Comment: Oops, did't mention reg things. TypeGuessRows-0 does the job! You save my day. Thank you much!

Comment: Did you have to use the 32 bit or 64 bit settings? Just for anyone else that comes along.

Comment: 64 bit, will add to the post above.

Answer (score 0):

Possible **workaround**:

Add 1st data row to the excel with values of the correct type and then just exclude it from your results.